# vim: plugin that allows me to jump from opening div to closing div in HTML?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm having a difficult time to find an opening div in deeply nested HTML that has been poorly written. Is there a plugin out there that will give me support to jump to the equivalent open/closing div using vim/gvim/macvim and other variants?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use matchit.vim. I land on the tag and just hit `%` and it jumps.

Comment: I have matchit.vim enabled, but it doesn't want to match div tags.. perhaps I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: Did you do :set ft=html or whatever for your html files? What does :set ft? give you

Comment: :set ft gives me filetype html

Comment: also, my file doesn't end in .html, it's foo.html.erb.. not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try [xmledit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301). Works for XML, HTML, and SGML.